# как вычесть от нынешней даты прошедшую datetime

Tags: c#

написать сколько на данный момент от этой даты к нынешней человеку лет
*дата 6 февраля 2019

```
DateTime dateYear = new DateTime(2019, 02, 6);
    DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now;
    int resultYear = (int)(dateYear - date2).TotalDays;
    Console.WriteLine(resultYear);
```

как привести к годам

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1404/12888024

Comment: @aepot пришел к такому решению
в ответе

Answer (score 0):

пришел к такому решению ыы незнаю как это на деле правильно ли

```
 DateTime dateYear = new DateTime(2019, 02, 6);
        int resultYear = (int)((date2 - dateYear) / 365).TotalDays;
        
        Console.WriteLine( "возраст человека равен = " + result );
```

Comment: Это решение не точное, точное по ссылке под вопросом. Во-первых вы не учитываете годы, где 366 дней, во-вторых операции вычислений с плавающей точкой имеют погрешность. Например если у меня близко день рождения, эта формула может выдать неверный результат. А формула по ссылке соаботает верно с точностью до секунды.